# R using mutate with loop for variable comparison

Tags: r, loops, comparison, dplyr

I have a dataframe with some old and new columns (say A_old,B_old,... and A_new,B_new,..) and I want to identify if they have changed given a certain condition.

I have written the following code to illustrate a **simplified** example with two fields (A & B) for comparison. Ideally I want to extend it to hundreds of fields so I don't want to re-type the **case_when** again and again.

In terms of cleanliness of the script, I am wondering if you have any suggestion for writing some clean codes for the example below (maybe with loops).

```
library(dplyr)

# Create a dummy dataframe
temp <-data.frame(A_new = c(0,0,1)
           ,A_old = c(1,0,0)
           ,B_new = c(0,0,1)
           ,B_old = c(0,0,0)
           ,cond = c(F,T,T)
           )

# variable for comparison
var_comparison <- c('A','B')

# Compare old and new together with an extra condition
temp <- temp %>%
  mutate(
  A_CHG = case_when(
    cond & A_new!=A_old ~ 1,
    TRUE ~ 0
    )
  ,B_CHG = case_when(
    cond & B_new!=B_old ~ 1,
    TRUE ~ 0
  )
)
```

Output:

```
  A_new A_old B_new B_old  cond A_CHG B_CHG
1     0     1     0     0 FALSE     0     0
2     0     0     0     0  TRUE     0     0
3     1     0     1     0  TRUE     1     1
```

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this by reshaping your data from wide to long format, do your comparisons and then transform it back.

Note: the solution below requires consistent naming patterns of your variables, i.e. they all need to be in the format "X_text". If that's not the case, you might need to change the `names_pattern` part below.

UPDATED to better reflect the original variable names.

```
library(tidyverse)
temp %>%
  mutate(id = 1:n()) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -c(cond, id),
               names_to = c("set", ".value"),
               names_pattern = "(.)_(.*)") %>%
  mutate(CHG = if_else(cond == TRUE & new != old, 1, 0)) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = c(id, cond),
              values_from = c(old, new, CHG),
              names_from = set,
              names_glue = "{set}_{.value}") %>%
  select(-id)
```

which gives:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 7
  cond  A_old B_old A_new B_new A_CHG B_CHG
  <lgl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 FALSE     1     0     0     0     0     0
2 TRUE      0     0     0     0     0     0
3 TRUE      0     0     1     1     1     1
```

Answer (score 1):

In base R, you can divide the dataframe into two groups, compare them directly and add them as new columns.

```
new_cols <- grep('new', names(temp), value = TRUE)
old_cols <- grep('old', names(temp), value = TRUE)
temp[sub('new', 'CHG', new_cols)] <- +(temp$cond & temp[new_cols] != temp[old_cols])
temp

#  A_new A_old B_new B_old  cond A_CHG B_CHG
#1     0     1     0     0 FALSE     0     0
#2     0     0     0     0  TRUE     0     0
#3     1     0     1     0  TRUE     1     1
```